# Unable to connect PostgreSQL 9.5 from QGIS 2.14.1

Tags: qgis, postgresql

I created new database called "shashi" in PgAdmin III. In QGIS to create new connection I entered following details.

**In PostgreSQL 9.5**
pgAdmin lll
Please enter password for user postgres on server PostgreSQL 9.5: ****

**In QGIS**
Create a New PostGIS Connection
Name: shashidhar
Service:
Host: localhost
Port: 5432
Database: postgres
SSL mode: disable

Authentication
Username: postgres
Password: **** (same password that I used in pgAdmin lll to connect to the server )

**Test connection ERROR:**
Connection failed-consult message log for details

Comment: I am completely new to databases.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have confused the username and the database name.

If you created a database called shashi, you should have Database: shashi in the QGIS PostGIS Connection window. Your username is likely postgres.

If that doesn't work, look in the message log. My logs are in /usr/local/pgsql/var/, but they may be somewhere else on your machine.

Comment: Also...If your PG database & QGIS installed in different PC then you have to grant your IP (QGIS PC IP) @ POSTGIS pg.hba conf file to get full DB access...

Comment: Yes, I tried with Database: Shashi in the QGIS PostGIS connection window and username: postgres, Still unable to connect to the database.

Comment: Can you post your message log? Also try the `CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS` as lejedi76 suggests.

Answer (score 2):

You can not connect to your database in Qgis if your dB is not spatial.
Please run `CREATE EXTENSION POSTGIS;` on your db in pgadminIII and
Retry to connect

Comment: Can you Please give steps of where to write that query "CREAT EXTENSION POSTGIS;

Comment: Do you have pgadmin3 installed? Simply open a query and execute `CREATE EXTENSION postgis;`. Have a look at this tutorial if you've never used pgadmin: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHXLNtiCI1U